# Spring MVC - dealing with reference data from the database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a table:

```
municipality_code | municipality_name
M01               | bogo
M02               | balamban
M03               | boljoon
```

Currently, I have a service method that calls a repository method which returns a Map of all the municipalities. The service is then called in all controllers. That means that, every time the service is called, the municipalities will be queried from the database. I was reading on http://springtips.blogspot.com/2008/09/lazy-loading-vs-pre-loading-beans-with.html, am in the right direction?

What is the best way to implement this? 
Would it be better if the municipalities will be queried just once, e.g. preloaded?

Comment: What actually is your question/problem?

Comment: My apologies. I've just edited my question.

Comment: Would it be better if the municipalities will be queried just once, e.g. preloaded?

Comment: Where is the quetion? Can you please elaborate in more details.

Comment: @googone11 Do you want to cache the results or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy loading vs. pre-loading seems to be solving a slightly different problem than the one you report: It prevents multiple selects in a row when you retrieve an entity and then retrieve its children via some getter methods. *(Lazy loading would issue a query for the parent entity first, followed by a query for each child being retrieved, while pre-loading enables Hibernate to issue a single query to retrieve all relevant children in one go.)*

You need to retrieve the same entity over and over again and want to prevent it from being queried more times than necessary (that is probably, more than once). This is a case for caching mechanism. Hibernate supports caching on different levels and with different strategies. Googling for ["hibernate caching"](https://www.google.com/search?q=hibernate%20caching) will give you a good start.